# PDO PHP MYSQL mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have tried for hours to get this to work.

```
<?php

require_once('inc.connect.php');

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' )
{
    if( isset( $_REQUEST ))
    {
        $type  = array_keys($_REQUEST)[0];
        $value = $_REQUEST[$type];
        if( $value === null )
        {
            $where_like = null;
        }
        else
        {
            $where_like = ' WHERE ' . $type . '_name LIKE ?';
        }

        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DBNAME . ';charset=UTF8', MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        $sql_statement = 'SELECT :' . $type . '_id, :' . $type . '_name FROM report_' . $type . $where_like;

        $sql_prepare = $db->prepare( $sql_statement );

        if( !(is_null($where_like)) ) $sql_prepare->bindValue(1, '"%' . $value . '%"', PDO::PARAM_STR);

        try{ 

            while( $sql_result = $sql_prepare->execute() )
            {
                $return[$sql_result[$type . '_id']] = $sql_result[$type . '_name'];
            }

            $return_JSON = json_encode($return);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $exception){

           return $exception->getMessage();
        } 
        echo "exception: ".$exception;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this ...

**Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Comment: Prepared Statements are not used like this. Use a predefined query and don't generate it at runtime. Look up a tutorial and rewrite your whole code.

Comment: Why not?  I know they're not typically used like this, but I don't see anything wrong with dynamically creating the query.

Comment: If there is nothing wrong why doesn't it work? It is best to use a predefined query. It is clear, understandable and not a pain to debug as you see right now.

Comment: Why you are using prepared statements at all?

Comment: Because this file is going to handle hundreds of different iterations of the same general query.  Anyone have a constructive answer?  Or one that uses clearly defined logic in place of ...

Comment: I don't mean arrogant commands.  Again, clearly defined logic please.  Telling me it's not how it's used is the most uninformed answer one could get.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you need clearly defined logic for your SQL in the first place. Or, at least - a clearly defined syntax.

Comment: As well, please tell me how my code is a tip-off the db has an "awful" design.  The more I interact with the structure I've created, the more I love it.

Comment: Also, how did I get this to work? Magic?  Was it magic guys?  I'm scared at the sudden realization that I may have supernatural powers.  Please, help.

Comment: @juergend - "If there is nothing wrong why doesn't it work?" ... I love that you said this! Upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I love about having a stable job is that I no longer have to worry about what my stackoverflow posts look like to potential employers.  In that spirit, **Your Common Sense** and **juergen d** can both "take a walk" for being such uncooperative "so-and-sos".

**This an AJAX response requested by the jQueryUI autocomplete({ source }) option.**

Here's my finished, working code...

```
<?php

require_once('inc.connect.php');

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' )
{
    if( isset( $_REQUEST ))
    {
        $type  = array_keys($_REQUEST)[0];

        if( in_array( $type, ['category', 'sub_category', 'names', 'report_searches', 'report_favs'] ))
        {
            $value  = $_REQUEST[$type];
            $id     = $type . '_id';
            $name   = $type . '_name';
            $table  = 'research_' . $type;
            $where  = $name;
            $like   = '%' . $value . '%';

            $value === null ? $where_like = null : $where_like = ' WHERE ' . $where . ' LIKE ?';

            $sql_db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DBNAME . ';charset=UTF8', MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
            $sql_statement = 'SELECT ' . $id . ', ' . $name . '  FROM ' . $table . $where_like;
            $sql_prepare = $sql_db->prepare( $sql_statement );

            if( !($value === null) ) $sql_prepare->bindParam(1, $like);

            try{
                if( $sql_prepare->execute() )
                {
                    while( $sql_result = $sql_prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
                    {
                        $return[$sql_result[$id]] = $sql_result[$name];
                    }

                    echo json_encode($return);
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```